# I am having trouble when startingup my PC, the processes tab in task manager is swamped by LULnchr.exe

Tags: windows-xp

Can anyone please tell me how to remove LULnchr.exe from my pc? Sometimes when pc does not start a message came up "LULnchr.exe Application Error.the application failed to initialise properly.(0x0000142)Click on OK to terminate application" My OS is Windows XP 34bit.
 I saw the text for the same thing but it was for Windows Vista 64 bit,but did not know if it could be used on my system.I hope this info is enough,Regards R.Miller.

Answer (score 0):

It's the automatic updater for Logitech devices, probably mouse, keyboard, scanner or webcam. Either get an updated version off the web, or un-install anything Logitech from Add/Remove Programs.

Answer (score 0):

lulnchr.exe is known as Logitech Updater (LU) and it is developed by Logitech, Inc.
You can remove from Start > Control Panel > Add/Remove programs .

Answer (score 0):

Check Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services to see if it is set to run automatically; if so you should set it to Disabled.  It if it a program that you can remove, I would just remove it.  You might also want to go to Logitech's website to download the newest drivers for Vista if any.